# How to add a new device to a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I would like to edit a distribution provisioning profile so I can add / remove devices.

Basically, the following documentation page from Apple shows us how to do it easily... But since they updated the portal, I don't know how to do it anymore...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011211-CH3-SW1

Comment: They have indeed updated it, and much better it is too.  I can see no reason why you can't extrapolate from that documentation - there is an equivalent in the new UI for what you need to achieve.

Comment: So it seems like there is no way to add devices to an existing distribution profile... The only way to do it is to delete the existing profile and create a new one.

Comment: But we can still edit an existing development profile to add/remove devices... I don't understand why they are not allowing us to do the same thing with the distribution profiles.

Comment: @Marko : the new UI doesn't allow us to do it anymore. If anyone can, please tell me.

Comment: I take that back - it doesn't - the ADC forums seem quiet on the subject, but they are probably the appropriate place to ask about this in any case.

Comment: @Marko it looks like there's a javascript hack to fix this issue. https://gist.github.com/ashtom/d0aeb62eedbfd555b04e

Comment: The question should not be downvoted IMHO, it's a valid problem. I have exactly the same problem and using the gist is not a real solution.

Comment: @user2257569 Please post it as a solution and accept your own answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, since the device list is only appearing for development profiles, there's a javascript hack that enables us to fix this issue for distribution profiles.

https://gist.github.com/ashtom/d0aeb62eedbfd555b04e

EDIT : Apple fixed the issue. The device list is now displayed for distribution profiles.