# I still can't add my device to my mac distribution provision profile

Tags: xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

this is really frustrating, as of today I still can't add my device to my distribution provision profile (mac dev program)

what I did was, I first created a new wildcard development provision profile, inside this profile I can add my device (my macbook air) without any problem.

I then created a new wildcard distribution profile, it asked for my certification (which is good), and then asked for my profile name, but it never asked for my device!

Also edit doesn't work, it just doesn't show the device section

I have also tried this hack:

https://gist.github.com/ashtom/d0aeb62eedbfd555b04e

when I select "insert device" from my bookmark, the device section does show up, however I can't save the profile (keeps loading and loading and never save!)

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make distribution profile, then there is no need to add device for it. You need to add device ID only for development profile.

Comment: then I'm confused. If so how come some other people asked about:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879245/how-to-add-a-new-device-to-a-provisioning-profile, some comes up with the javascript hack and some even says apple already fixed it??

Comment: let me know weather you want to create distribution profile or development. If you want to publish your application to iTunes, then there is no need to add device.In fact, it will not allow you to add device. While if you want to test application in development stage, then you must add devices in profile.

Comment: I want to publish my app outside the mac appstore. I have created both distribution and development profiles. For development profile I can add my device without any trouble. But for distribution profile I can't do so. I totally understand what you're saying, but what you explained to me is contradicting this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879245/how-to-add-a-new-device-to-a-provisioning-profile if you visit the above link, someone was trying to add the device to the distribution profile, and some even comes up with the javascript hack.

Comment: He's talking about Beta Testing through ad hoc, and you certainly need an ID for that...unless that's changed in recent weeks.